How to XSL-transform an XML-file which has paths to two different dictionaries xmls and make it to one lexicon
lexicon.xml file has paths to two dictionaries and path to the logo. The dictionaries contain 10 words each one in English and one in Swedish.
lexicon.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="lexikon.xsl"?>
<lexicon>
    <wordlist1>xml_english.xml</wordlist1>
    <wordlist2>xml_swedish.xml</wordlist2>
    <editor>Simon Bale</editor>
    <logo>logo.svg</logo>
</lexicon>

XML dictionary in Swedish
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xml_style.css"?>
<wordlist
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation = "xsd_ordlista.xsd">
    <language>Svenska</language>
    <author>Karl Jonsson</author>
    <words>
        <word>natt</word>
        <word>dag</word>
        <word>vatten</word>
        <word>bil</word>
        <word>sol</word>
        <word>himmel</word>
        <word>stad</word>
        <word>hus</word>
        <word>katt</word>
        <word>regn</word>
    </words>
</wordlist>

XML dictionary in English
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="xml_style.css"?>
<wordlist>
   <language>English</language>
   <author>David Cahill</author>
   <words>
      <word>night</word>
      <word>day</word>
      <word>water</word>
      <word>car</word>
      <word>sun</word>
      <word>sky</word>
      <word>city</word>
      <word>house</word>
      <word>cat</word>
      <word>rain</word>
   </words>
</wordlist>

XSL file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict" >
    <xsl:output
            method="xml"
            indent="yes"
            encoding="iso-8859-1"
    />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Lexicon</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xml_style.css"/> 
            </head>
            <body>
                <image src="logo.svg" alt="Logo"/>
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="/wordlist/language"/>
                </h1>
                <h2><xsl:value-of select="/wordlist/author"/>
                </h2>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/wordlist/words/word">
                        <li>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

I want to transform the XML file containing the logo and the paths to dictionaries to a lexicon. But I am stuck and not sure if I am doing right.

There is a document function in XSLT 1.0 and additionally a doc function in XSLT 2.0 and later. In current versions of XSLT/XPath there is a function like for-each-pair that could help process the sequence of word elements from both diccionaries pairwise.

@Filburt The xsl:include instruction is used to include another XSLT stylesheet, not for additional XML source documents.

@michael.hor257k my bad - mixed those up and didn't verify the answer on the duplicate I thought I had found.

@Sunreuz Please edit your question and add the exact result you expect to get. If the xml_swedish.xml file is part of the input, post it too.

You can inline the dictionaries documents as a parameters or variables (as done below for self-containedness of the sample) or use the document function to read in the dictionary documents (shown in the code in comments):
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">
  
  <!-- <xsl:param name="dic-en" select="document(lexicon/wordlist1)"/> -->
  <xsl:param name="dic-en">
<wordlist>
   <language>English</language>
   <author>David Cahill</author>
   <words>
      <word>night</word>
      <word>day</word>
      <word>water</word>
      <word>car</word>
      <word>sun</word>
      <word>sky</word>
      <word>city</word>
      <word>house</word>
      <word>cat</word>
      <word>rain</word>
   </words>
</wordlist>
  </xsl:param>
  
  <!-- <xsl:param name="dic-se" select="document(lexicon/wordlist2)"/> -->
  <xsl:param name="dic-se">
<words>
   <word>natt</word>
   <word>dag</word>
   <word>vatten</word>
   <word>bil</word>
   <word>sol</word>
   <word>himmel</word>
   <word>stad</word>
   <word>hus</word>
   <word>katt</word>
   <word>regn</word>
</words>
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>English</th>
              <th>Swedish</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$dic-en//word"/>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="word">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$dic-se//word[$pos]"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Note that inlining the content as I have done it requires an XSLT 2 or later processor but the suggested document use should work with an XSLT 1 processor as well.
Online sample using SaxonJS 2.6 creates a table like
English     Swedish
night   natt
day     dag
water   vatten
car     bil
sun     sol
sky     himmel
city    stad
house   hus
cat     katt
rain    regn

XSLT 1.0 example is online at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2024/two-dictionaries-example1.xml, used XSLT is at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2024/merge-dics.xsl.

It looks like this when I run the lexicon.xml file in the browser: xml_english.xml xml_swedish.xml Simon Bale logo.svg

@Sunreuz, which XSLT processor do you use? Do you use the example with the document function? Is the XSLT processor set up/configured to allow the use of the doument function?

Sorry, I am not sure which but I use version="2.0" and I think it would be better to use the the document function like this: 

@Sunreuz, don't get distracted by the inlined data, that is just to have a self-contained full executable sample. Of course, if you have separated files, use the document function instead, as I had shown in comments. I have added a link to an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet and XML sample using the document function.

@Sunreuz, another? In addition to https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2024/merge-dics.xsl?

could you please give me an example of how I could do this with document function, I feel a bit lost however I have tried to do something.

@Sunreuz, you haven't managed to explain why https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2024/merge-dics.xsl and https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2024/two-dictionaries-example1.xml don't help. They are online, so they work in the browser. Unless you are running in an environment where the document function is disabled for security reasons, that example should work. And if the document function is disabled then it is not the XSLT code that needs to be changed, rather the security settings of the code performing the XSLT transformation.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Lexicon</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div>
                <img src="{lexicon/logo}"/>
                <h1>Swedish - English</h1>
                <div>
                    <h2>Swedish - English</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:for-each select="lexicon/wordlist1">
                            <li><xsl:value-of select="word"/></li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>English - Swedish</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:for-each select="lexicon/wordlist2">
                            <li><xsl:value-of select="word"/></li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


@MartinHonnen above

Is that an answer? Why on earth would you put HTML elements in the namespace http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict? That is not a namespace a browser will recognize.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

using XI namespace
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

    <!-- Define variable to hold the merged content -->
    <xsl:variable name="mergedContent">
        <!-- Include content from xml_english.xml -->
        <xi:include href="xml_english.xml"/>
        <!-- Include content from xml_swedish.xml -->
        <xi:include href="xml_swedish.xml"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- Main template to process the merged content -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <!-- Process the merged content -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="$mergedContent"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add other templates as needed for processing -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

    <!-- Define variable to hold the merged content -->
    <xsl:variable name="mergedContent">
        <!-- Include content from xml_english.xml -->
        <xi:include href="xml_english.xml"/>
        <!-- Include content from xml_swedish.xml -->
        <xi:include href="xml_swedish.xml"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- Main template to process the merged content -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <output>
            <!-- Process the merged content -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="$mergedContent"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Add other templates as needed for processing -->

</xsl:stylesheet>


Could you please elaborate why you have duplicate xsl stylesheets and what is that I have to add in that code?

This cannot work the way you imagine. Please test your answers before posting.
